# Programmatically checking a ion-radio from TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a pretty simple question but I can't find any answer. I have this code :

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="profile_activities" name="activities">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Option 1</ion-label>
        <ion-radio  (ionSelect)='selectedActivity($event);' value="0"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Option 2</ion-label>
        <ion-radio (ionSelect)='selectedActivity($event);' value="1"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Option 3</ion-label>
        <ion-radio (ionSelect)='selectedActivity($event);' value="2"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

... and I would just like to pre-check a value from typescript based on an info I get from my database. How can I check a ion-radio from Typescript?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by pre-check? can we have more info?

Comment: @Sampath I would like to check a ion-radio after getting an info from the backend. For example, the backend responds that the first value has to be checked, then, I check the first value according to this response.

Comment: @fraxool setting value directly to `this.profile_activities`(ngModel) inside Component should work.. as its two way binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, managed to find the answer by myself. In TypeScript, I just need to enter the default value of the radio to be checked like that :

```
this.profile_activities = "1";
```

... for example, in the `ionViewWillEnter()` function and the radio with `value="1"` is checked !

Answer (score 0):

in my case ionic 6, angular 12

if worked like this

```
<ion-list radio-group value="{{profile_activities}}" name="activities">
......
```